# Number of matrices with bounded products of rows and columns

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrices, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

Fix an integer $d \geq 2$ and for every real number $x$ let $M_d(x)$ be number of $d \times d$ matrices $(a_{ij})$ satisfying: every $a_{ij}$ is a positive integer, the product of every row does not exceed $x$, and the product of every column does not exceed $x$.

I'm looking for a good upper bound for $M_d(x)$ as $x \to +\infty$.

If we forget about the condition on the columns, since it is well known that the number of $d$-tuples $(b_1, \dots, b_d)$ of positive integers satisfying $b_1 \cdots b_d \leq x$ is $\ll_d x (\log x)^{d - 1}$ (a generalization of Dirichlet divisor problem), we get the upper bound 
$$M_d(x) \ll_d x^d (\log x)^{d(d-1)}.$$

In the special case $d = 2$, we have that $a_{12}, a_{21} \leq \min(x / a_{11}, x / a_{22})$ and consequently
$$M_2(x) \leq \sum_{a_{11}, a_{22} \leq x} \min\left(\frac{x}{a_{11}}, \frac{x}{a_{22}}\right)^2 \ll \sum_{a_{11} \leq a_{22} \leq x} \left(\frac{x}{a_{22}}\right)^2 \ll x^2 \log x ,$$
which is a better upper bound than the general one given in the above paragraph. However, I have no idea of how to generalize this trick to $d \geq 3$ (if possible).

Has this problem been studied before? Do you have any idea/suggestion about it?

Comment: Do you believe the $2\times 2$ bound is sharp?

Comment: @IgorRivin I don't have any heuristic supporting such belief.

Comment: It is obviously not far from sharp, since diagonal matrices give you $x^2.$

Comment: What happens when you take logarithms of the aij? Gerhard "Maybe Row-Sum Literature Will Help" Paseman, 2019.08.17.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I think logarithms do not help very much. They turn the problem from multiplicative to additive, but the variables are not integers anymore, making things much more difficult...

Comment: Of course. However, for lower bounds, you could focus on all row and column products being powers of two, and then look at the literature (of which I know nothing, sorry) on bounded row and column sums.  Perhaps you had tried logarithms and some other idea/wrong turn occurred to you that you were willing to share? Gerhard "Does Wrong Turns While Sleeping" Paseman, 2019.08.17.

Comment: I discuss a generalization in my post below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem was considered in passing in the proof of Theorem 4.1 in [Granville and Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9903196.pdf), see the argument starting at the bottom of page 17.  They show (in your notation) that $M_d(x)$ is of order $x^d (\log x)^{(d-1)^2}$.  You should also look at work of [Harper, Nikeghbali and Radziwill](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.01443.pdf) which shows an asymptotic formula for closely related objects (see Theorem 3 there).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Nice question. Some thoughts on lower bounds: for $d=2$, the order of magnitude $x^2\log x$ is correct—here is an argument giving such a lower bound.

For any real numbers $U,V$ such that $UV=x$ (and say $U,V\ge2$), any $2\times 2$ matrix such that $a_{11},a_{22}\in\big(\frac U2,U\big]$ and $a_{21},a_{12}\in\big(\frac V2,V\big]$ is counted by $M_2(x)$, and the number of such matrices is $\gg U^2V^2 = x^2$. We can sum this dyadic-interval lower bound over $U=2^k$ for a suitable range of $k$ to obtain the lower bound $M_2(x) \gg x^2\log x$.

A similar argument gives a lower bound for general $d\ge3$. If $U_1U_2\cdots U_d=x$, with the convention that $U_{d+j}=U_j$, then the matrices such that $a_{ij} \in \big( \frac{U_{i+j}}2, U_{i+j}\big]$ for all $1\le i,j\le d$ contribute $\gg U_1^d \cdots U_d^d = x^d$ to $M_d(x)$. We then sum over all $U_1=2^{k_1},\dots,U_d=2^{k_d}$ such that $k_1+\cdots+k_d\le(\log x)/\log 2$; the number of such $d$-tuples of positive integers is $\gg_d(\log x)^d$, giving the lower bound $M_d(x) \gg_d x^d(\log x)^d$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $M_d(x_1,y_1,\dotsc,x_d,y_d)$ be the number of matrices $(a_{ij})$ with positive integer entries such that the product of the $i$-th row is at most $x_i$, and the product of the $i$-th column is at most $y_i$. I claim that
$$M_d(x_1,y_1,\dotsc,x_d,y_d)\ll_d\sqrt{x_1y_1}\prod_{i=2}^d\sqrt{x_iy_i}\log(2x_iy_i)^{2i-3}.\tag{$\ast$}$$
In particular, this implies the bound in Lucia's response:
$$M_d(x)=M_d(x,x,\dotsc,x,x)\ll_d x^d\log(2x)^{(d-1)^2}.$$
We can prove $(\ast)$ by induction on $d$. For $d=1$ the statement is clear (the empty product means $1$). So let us assume that $d\geq 2$, and $(\ast)$ holds with $d-1$ in place of $d$.

For a matrix $(a_{ij})$ to be counted, let us abbreviate
$$s_i:=a_{id},\qquad t_j:=a_{dj},\qquad a:=a_{dd}.$$ Then we see that
\begin{align*}M_d(x_1,y_1,\dotsc,x_d,y_d)
&\ll_d\sum_{a\leq\sqrt{x_dy_d}}\sum_{\substack{s_1\dots s_{d-1}\leq y_d/a\\t_1\dots t_{d-1}\leq x_d/a}}M_{d-1}\left(\frac{x_1}{s_1},\frac{y_1}{t_1},\dotsc,\frac{x_{d-1}}{s_{d-1}},\frac{y_{d-1}}{t_{d-1}}\right)\\
&\ll_d\sum_{a\leq\sqrt{x_dy_d}}\sum_{\substack{s_1\dots s_{d-1}\leq y_d/a\\t_1\dots t_{d-1}\leq x_d/a}}\sqrt{\frac{x_1y_1}{s_1t_1}}\prod_{i=2}^{d-1}\sqrt{\frac{x_iy_i}{s_it_i}}\log(2x_iy_i)^{2i-3}.
\end{align*}
On the right hand side, we observe that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{s_1\dots s_{d-1}\leq y_d/a\\t_1\dots t_{d-1}\leq x_d/a}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{s_1t_1\dots s_{d-1}t_{d-1}}}
&=\left(\sum_{m\leq x_d/a}\frac{\tau_{d-1}(m)}{\sqrt{m}}\right)
\left(\sum_{n\leq y_d/a}\frac{\tau_{d-1}(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\
&\ll_d\frac{\sqrt{x_dy_d}}{a}\log(2x_dy_d)^{2d-4}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we can bound $M_d(x_1,y_1,\dotsc,x_d,y_d)$ as
\begin{align*}M_d(\cdots)
&\ll_d\sqrt{x_1y_1}\left(\prod_{i=2}^{d-1}\sqrt{x_iy_i}\log(2x_iy_i)^{2i-3}\right)\sum_{a\leq\sqrt{x_dy_d}}\frac{\sqrt{x_dy_d}}{a}\log(2x_dy_d)^{2d-4}\\
&\ll_d\sqrt{x_1y_1}\prod_{i=2}^d\sqrt{x_iy_i}\log(2x_iy_i)^{2i-3}.
\end{align*}
The proof of $(\ast)$ is complete.

Comment: @Lucia: I fixed my original argument (which is not the one I posted here earlier).

Comment: Hi GH: Looks good!

Comment: @Lucia: Thanks! Of course it is standard, but I felt bad about my mistake earlier.